# IFileDialog Overwrite File and Open Folder/File

Tags: c++, winapi

I have two issues related to `IFileSaveDialog` & `IFileOpenDialog` I did not managed to find a solution for, I hope you can help me.

1. When the user is saving a file with an existing name, the "Confirm Save As" prompt appears. I need the "Yes" option to be marked as default instead of "No".

[image]

2. The User can open/load a file or a folder from the same dialog.

Can these be done with this API? Or maybe other API?

I tried to google it and go over Microsoft documentation to find a solution, but with no luck.

Comment: 1) I don't think there's an official option as this is clearly a standard UI recommendation to have the "no" by default. Can't find it anyway 2) you can use IFileDialog::SetOptions(...FOS_PICKFOLDERS ...) but you'll have only folders. There's no common dialog that can select folders and files, only folders or files.

Comment: For 1) you can use the [`IFileDialogEvents::OnOverwrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialogevents-onoverwrite) event to display your own prompt, such as with [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect), then you can make it display whatever text and default button you want.

Comment: IFileDialog::Get/SetOptions() to turn off FOS_OVERWRITEPROMPT

Comment: @HansPassant `IFileDialogEvents::OnOverwrite` requires `FOS_OVERWRITEPROMPT` be enabled

Comment: That comment was not directed you.  The point is to avoid scaring the bejeezus out of the user with the overwrite warning.

Comment: `The User can open/load a file or a folder from the same dialog.`  Can you describe some of these details?  What does the same dialog mean?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Hi, yes I want that the user can choose in the open dialog both files and folders, so the user will have the option to load all the presets from some folder or only one preset dependents on his selection in the open dialog(IFileOpenDialog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. When the user is saving a file with an existing name, the "Confirm Save As" prompt appears. I need the "Yes" option to be marked as
>    default instead of "No".

As @Remy Lebeau said that, you can use [IFileDialogEvents::OnOverwrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialogevents-onoverwrite) method. And use `MessageBox` to create a suitable dialog.

Some code:

```
 IFACEMETHODIMP OnOverwrite(IFileDialog* , IShellItem*psi, FDE_OVERWRITE_RESPONSE* response) {  
        int msgboxID = MessageBox(
            NULL,
            (LPCWSTR)L"Windows already exists,                 \n\rDo you want to replace it?",
            (LPCWSTR)L"Confirm Save As",
            MB_ICONWARNING | MB_YESNO | MB_DEFBUTTON1
        );

        switch (msgboxID)
        {
        case IDYES:
            *response = FDEOR_ACCEPT;
            break;
        case IDNO:
            *response = FDEOR_REFUSE;
            break;  
        } 
        return S_OK; 
    }
```

Debug:

[image: 1]

> The User can open/load a file or a folder from the same dialog. Can
> these be done with this API? Or maybe other API?

There is no such method in the document, you can only select a folder or file.

As a compromise, I suggest that you can create a new MessageBox and set two buttons in it, namely "select folders" and "select files". When the user selects folders, folder dialog with the `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` style is opened. Otherwise, Files is selected by default.